# How do you correctly loop after an error is catched?

Tags: java

I have my database project going on. 
Contains following classes:

`Main`

`StudentCollection`

`Student`

Inside my `StudentCollection` class I have the following method/query:

```
public Students getStudentForIndex(int index){
    try {
        return list.get(index);
    }catch(InputMismatchException e){
        System.out.println("Incorrect character entered");
        return null;
    }
}
```

I would like to get your suggestions on how I should tackle looping through the method.

Reason - If user inputs an error, I want to warn the user of that error and ask him to input again, continuously catching the possible errors thrown

Comment: Why are you expecting `list.get(index)` to throw an `InputMismatchException`?

Comment: That's one of the error that get's thrown: http://prntscr.com/3jqk3u

Comment: If you want to catch that exception then *the line of code that throws it* needs to be the one that's covered by the `try` block. Assuming that `list` is actually a subtype of `java.util.List`, that section of code **cannot** generate an `InputMismatchException`. Consequently, that `catch` block cannot ever execute, meaning anything inside it is "dead code" (that is, code that cannot be executed no matter what path you take through the application).

Comment: Oh alright! Understood, thanks JonK! So it's not possible to try catch from within the method itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
boolean finished = false;
Student s;

while (!finished) {
    s = getStudentForIndex(getInput());
    if (s != null)
        finished = true;
}

// Do stuff with the Student s here.
```

The loop will loop until `finished` is true. This gets the input and passes it into the `getStudentForIndex` method. If that input causes an `InputMismatchException`, then `s` will be null. If `s` is not null, then you're done and finished can be true.

Comment: @Booch if that answers your question at all then you might clic on that symbol called "Accept Answer" so it's a way to thank the answerer

Comment: I have to wait 2 more minutes as it won't allow me to accept the answer so soon :)

Comment: @Frakcool Before you write that comment, check to see if the person has asked questions and accepted answer before. If they haven't, take initiative and tell them!

Comment: @AnubianNoob Ok, then sorry, my mistake :)

Comment: @AnubianNoob may I suggest that you add a bit of an explanation to your answer? It helps not only our question asker, but others viewing this issue to get a true explanation of how it works and why it does.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a `Scanner` to get your input, it is as simple as:

```
Scanner in;
int input = -1;
// While the input number does not validly reference a student in the array...
while(input < 0 || input >= list.size()) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the student number");
    // Will wait until the user returns an int. Not a char, or string, an int.
    input = in.nextInt(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's worth distinguishing between bad input and the case where the input is valid but results in no students (separation of concerns).  You need one method that keeps attempting to read input until it gets something it likes.  Then another method that acts on the input.  This will make it easier to test each feature of your program independent of the others.

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static class Student { 
        private final String id;
        public Student(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String toString() {
            return id;
        }
    }

    public static class StudentCollection {
        private final List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(
          new Student("zero"),
          new Student("one"),
          new Student("two"),
          new Student("three")
        );

        public int getMinIndex() { return 0; } 
        public int getMaxIndex() { return students.size() - 1; }

        public Student getStudentForIndex(int index) {
            return students.get(index);
        }

    }

    public static String promptForIndex(Scanner reader, PrintWriter writer) {
        writer.write(String.format("Enter an index: %n"));
        writer.flush();
        return reader.nextLine().trim();
    }

    public static int parseInput(String s, int min, int max) {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(s);
        if(value < min || value > max) return -1;
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(System.out);
            final int retries = 10;

            StudentCollection sc = new StudentCollection();

            int index = -1;
            int loopCounter = retries;
            while(loopCounter > 0) {
                loopCounter--;
                String input = promptForIndex(reader, writer);
                try {
                    index = parseInput(input, sc.getMinIndex(), sc.getMinIndex());
                    if(index == -1) {
                        System.out.println("invalid index [" + input + "] must be in range ("
                       + sc.getMinIndex() + "," + sc.getMaxIndex() + ") try again");
                    } else {
                        loopCounter = 0;
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("invalid input ["+input+"], try again");
                }
            }

            if(index == -1) {
                System.out.println("failed after "+retries+" attempts");
            } else {
                System.out.println("found student '" + sc.getStudentForIndex(index) 
                        + "' @ index [" + index + "]");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I'm grasping your idea.. would it be too much to ask for a sample code displaying this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int index;
Students students;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter index: ");
    index = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    students = studentCollection.getStudentForIndex(index);
} while (students == null);
in.close();
```